# Django defer() and only() queryset not working?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

Please guide me if i misunderstand the correct use of defer() or only() in queryset.

This is the code where i am trying to get only seleted fields data from Donor model to make process fast because it has 2000 entries and when i use all() it takes time to fetch data.

```
def donor(request):
        # donors = Donors.objects.all()
        donors = Donors.objects.only('donorid','donor_type','title','donor_name','address',
                                       'mobile_no','jamatkhana')
        # donors = Donors.objects.defer('donorid','donor_type','title','donor_name','address',
                                       'mobile_no','jamatkhana')
        return render(request,"hod_template/add_donor_template.html",{"donors":donors})
```

After use of "only()" or "defer()" the result is still same as "all()" none of the selected field neither deferred nor only. even it takes more time to load than all().

Please tell me how to get only these selected field data from donor model. i also tell you i tried "Values()" Method as well but the problem is the "jamatkhana" field is ForeignKey and i want its data as well. but using of "Values()" method it only get values not foreignkey inner data.
hope i explain properly?

Comment: `.defer()` and `.only()` will still provide the same objects, but it will *postpone* fetching the fields. If your template still needs these items, it will make extra queries, so it can take extra time to load these.

Comment: It thus depends on the attributes you are rendering in the template.

Comment: So please the parts of your template where you are *rendering* data.

Comment: `.defer` and `.only` are also each other's counterparts, so it makes no sense that these contains the same list of values.

Comment: I would like to ask do you really need to display 2000 entries on one page? Nobody can really read that I believe... Perhaps you should be using pagination?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat , basically i used Datatable plugin to generate and view report in Excel and Pdf. so if i dont call all 2000 entreis and use pagination method how would i generate reports of all entries. i know we can make our own pagination, Excel and pdf formats but it will takes lot of programming which Datatable plugin solve it.

Comment: @manasiyasumail In this case you should consider using ajax to load the data. I have not used datatables before but just searching "Django datatables" or "Django datatables ajax" there are some packages that look promising and make it easy to use datatables with Django.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Just forget about 'defer' method yet we take only 'only' method. in my template i used these selected fields only in Datatable although there are some other fields as well in donor model but i not call them in template only these fields are important to show in reports. so i read in django documentation that 'only' method reduce time and load only data by giving fields name in it. so it not working like that.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, ajax is good for load data the only problem with ajax is it only load json format by doing json format django view has to create json dict. so if model has foreignkey field so how we can create json dict with foreignkey data as well.

Comment: @manasiyasumail: yes, it reduces time, **but** that is not the bottleneck *at all*, loading 2'000 records, even if these contain some extra fields, will often not take more than a millisecond. Since you are rendering data from a *related* object, you have an *N+1* problem. You should simply load all the data from the related model with the *same* query. If you do not `.select_related` that model, it thus will make **2'001** queries, and that is the part that is likely the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

> but the problem is the `jamatkhana` field is `ForeignKey` and I want its data as well.

Likely fetching the related object that is referred to by the `ForeignKey` is the bottleneck. You can use [**`.select_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to make a `JOIN` at the database side and thus fetch the data of the related `jamatkhana` field with the same query. Without `.select_related(…)`, it will make an extra query *per* `Donor` to fetch the related data, and thus this easily results in a lot of extra queries to the database.

You thus can render this with:

```
donors = Donors.objects.select_related('jamatkhana')
```

As [@AbdulAzizBarkat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66397907/django-defer-and-only-queryset-not-working/66398006#comment117384341_66397907) however points out, typically [*pagination*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#pagination) is used to reduce the amount of data from the webserver to the client, and often by slicing a queryset, you also reduce the bandwidth (and sometimes the number of queries) from the database to the Django/Python layer.